# Keep a p element attached to an h2 when resizing the p element does not move

Tags: css, wordpress, element

```css
.uvc-main-heading p {
  position: relative;
  left: -8%;
  transform: rotate(-20deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="uvc-main-heading ult-responsive">
  <p style="text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;color:#800000;">NEW</p>
</div>
<div class="uvc-main-heading ult-responsive">
  <h2 style="font-weight:bold;color:#000000;">Open Stock</h2>
</div>
```

This positions it where I want it to be, but when I resize the browser the NEW element moves with it and I want it to stay put in position, but still scroll with the rest.

[Website on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01h5U.png)

[Website on Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAgyc.png)

I know I can use CSS and media queries to do each breakpoint, but I am trying to find a better solution

Thanks

Comment: We are missing some informations/code to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just move your new tag inside the heading and position it absolutely to the heading, then it's position will not change when relative to the heading:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;  /* for test only */
}

.uvc-main-heading {
  position: relative;    /* position new absolutely to this */
  display: inline-block; /* for test (so you can see it centred */
}

.uvc-main-heading p {
  /* position this absolutely */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* translation moves it left 25% it's ownb width and 100% up it's own height */
  transform: rotate(-20deg) translate(-25%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="uvc-main-heading ult-responsive">
  <h2 style="font-weight:bold;color:#000000;">Open Stock</h2>
  <p style="text-decoration:underline;font-weight:bold;color:#800000;">NEW</p>
</div>
```